# How to invoke async-operation on two-way bound Combobox (WPF)

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, combobox, properties, async-await

What's the appropriate way to handle running an async operation when an item is selected from a two-way bound control such as a combobox (wpf data binding)?

When I have a two-way binding property (e.g. SelectedValue on ComboBox) I don't think I can use [Stephen Cleary's NotifyTaskCompletion](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html)  because when a user selects a value from the dropdown, the ComboBox itself would need to modify the bound Result property, which is the Task's result.

The only viable solution I've come up with is calling an async Task -method from the databound setter without awaiting the result. This should be fine as long as the async-method triggers a property changed event for whatever ui-related stuff is being done, and that any exceptions are picked up and propagated to the ui accordingly, right?

I assume this would be a common case in async WPF applications. How do you guys approach this?

My solution so far:

```
<ComboBox 
        ItemsSource="{Binding PossibleItems}"
        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
        SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
```

...

```
public Item SelectedItem
{
    get { return m_selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        m_selectedItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();

        InitializeAsyncAndFirePropertyChanged();   // async Task method not awaited - gives compiler warning CS4014
    }
}

public async Task InitializeAsyncAndFirePropertyChanged(ObservableCollection<RFEnvironment> possibleRfEnvironments)
{
    //should check this method for exceptions and propagate them to the UI via databinding
    OtherDataBoundProperty = await GetSomeStringFromWebAsync(); 
}

public string OtherDataBoundProperty
{
    get { return m_otherDataBoundProperty; }
    set
    {
        m_otherDataBoundProperty = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Note: I have found similar questions asked, but none that addresses two-way bindings on controls such as a Combobox.

Comment: I run into a similar issue, but running async without awaiting is not good enough. What about exceptions? But have not found a better solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a functional reactive MVVM framework such as [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/), you would simply observe the `SelectedItem` property and kick off any operation you want when the property is set. e.g.:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SelectedItem)
    .Subscribe(async _ => await InitializeAsyncAndFirePropertyChanged());
```

A property itself should ne be kicking off background operations, but a view model may do this when a property is set.

Please refer to the docs for more information: https://reactiveui.net/docs/concepts/.

Comment: That looks interesting, and I might look into reactiveUI some time, but for now I'm looking for a way to solve this with plain MVVM and WPF.

Comment: Solve what exactly? A property can't be async.

Comment: How to best start an async operation when the user selects a value from a combobox dropdown.
The more I look at it I think there is no magic beautiful solution. I just need to make sure the setter returns immediately and in some way trigger an async method. The clue is to make sure the async-method calls the appropriate propertyChange-calls when finished, and also handle any errors that may occur by itself triggering propertyChange-calls for error-properties bound to UI-error indicators.

Comment: I have already answered that; Look into functional programming and set up this in the view model but not in the property itself. The other option would be to simply fire off the async operation in the property setter and then either forget about the results or hook up to some event that is raised once the async method has completed. And you are right, this isn't beautiful in any way :) ReactiveUI and similar libraries were made for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with `async` call in property setter when using WCF databinding. 
My solution is slightly better, because in your case when an exception occurs in `InitializeAsyncAndFirePropertyChanged`, no exception is thrown nor caught. The modified code is below. It uses task continuation to throw an exception and raising `OnPropertyChanged`. `OnPropertyChanged` call can stay in an original place, it depends on your needs.

```
public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private readonly TaskScheduler _uiScheduler;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        _uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    }

    public Item SelectedItem
    {
        get { return m_selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            m_selectedItem = value;
            InitializeAsyncAndFirePropertyChanged()
                .ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    if (t.Exception != null)
                    {
                        throw t.Exception;
                    }

                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }, _uiScheduler);
        }
    }

    public async Task InitializeAsyncAndFirePropertyChanged(ObservableCollection<RFEnvironment> possibleRfEnvironments)
    {
        //should check this method for exceptions and propagate them to the UI via databinding
        OtherDataBoundProperty = await GetSomeStringFromWebAsync();
    }

    public string OtherDataBoundProperty
    {
        get { return m_otherDataBoundProperty; }
        set
        {
            m_otherDataBoundProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    .... other code to support INotifyPropertyChanged
}
```